# consulta en Laravel con relación

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

estoy teniendo un problema y tal vez puedan iluminarme.
Tengo una tabla película y una tabla de categorías que tienen una relación de mucho a mucho. Lo que deseo es poder obtener las películas que tengan diferentes géneros. Pero ejemplo que me traiga todas las películas que tienen el genero 4 y 190 los dos géneros juntos. Pero en vez de tener ese comportamiento, el código que pongo a continuación me trae todas las películas que tengan el genero 4 y también todas las que tienen el género 190. Espero puedan ayudarme a conformar mi consulta. Saludos

```php
$generos = [4,190];
$peliculas = Pelicula::with('categories')
    ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($generos) {
        $query->whereIn('categorys.id', $generos)->where('type', 'pelicula');
    })->orderBy($this->orderBy, $this->orden)
    ->paginate(20);
```

[image: Modelo de BD]

Modelo de Películas

```
class Pelicula extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = [ 
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

Modelo de categorías

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $table = "categorys";

    public function peliculas() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pelicula','category_pelicula');
    }
}
```

Comment: En ese caso, en vez de usar `whereIn`, podrias usar clausulas `where`. Si no sabes que cantidad de elementos trae el array de generos, puedes agregar los `where` en un loop

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Hola, la cantidad de géneros es desconocida, intente probar un loop para ir agregando los where pero me sucede lo mismo, si selecciono un solo género trae los datos bien, pero cuando selecciono 2 géneros ya no trae nada. ` ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($g) {
         foreach ($g as $key => $value) {
                 query->where('categorys.id',$value)->where('type','pelicula');
           }
                 $query->where('type','pelicula');
                })
                ->orderBy($this->orderBy,$this->orden)
                ->paginate(20);

Comment: Podrías por favor poner en la pregunta la estructura de las 3 tablas (películas, categorías y la pivot)?

Comment: @azeós https://i.stack.imgur.com/plolj.jpg ahí está la estructura. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

**Pelicula.php**:

- Al usar el trait *SoftDeletes* no es necesario agregar `deleted_at` a `$dates`.
- A la relación `categories()` le agregaría el nombre de la tabla pivot (como lo hiciste en el modelo Category), por las dudas de que no esté resolviendo bien.

```
class Pelicula extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category', 'category_pelicula');
    }
}
```

El problema es que en el `where()` estás usando `categories.id`, y la tabla no se llama `categories`, se llama `categorys`. Te recomiendo que la renombres a `categories` para evitar futuros problemas (tendrías que sacar el `protected $table` del modelo).

Para traer las películas que tienen *ambas* categorías, tenés que concatenar múltiples `whereHas`:

```
$generos = [4, 190];

$peliculas = Pelicula::orderBy($this->orderBy, $this->orden);

foreach ($generos as $genero) {
    $peliculas->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($genero) {
        $query->where('categorys.id', $genero)->where('type', 'pelicula');
    });
}


$peliculas->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que trate de hacer la estructura lo más simple posible para mostrarla. He probado lo que me has puesto y tampoco me trae ningún resultado. En realidad no me inportaría tener que hacerlo con consultas sin los modelos. Igual si tienen alguna idea me ayudaría mucho. Saludos

Comment: Publicá por favor la estructura real de la base de datos (o al menos revisá los nombres) y los modelos de las 2 tablas. La consulta es correcta, la probé, pero tal vez tenés algo mal definido en las relaciones.

Comment: ya puse la imagen real de la estructura

Comment: Y publicá los archivos de los modelos "Pelicula" y "Category" por favor.

Comment: Listo, ya lo puse en la publicación

Comment: Fijate ahora mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo, realmente me has ayudado a resolver el problema en en el que llevava días. Gracias